# Convert postman api call to Node.js call

Tags: node.js, swagger, postman, swagger-2.0

I'm getting some troubles when trying to make a post request to an API made with swagger 2.0 (not by me).

I've imported a collection to postman, and when i perform a post request it works perfect. However in Node.js it outputs a 400 error with swagger library, and a 500 with axios.

Heres the schema that the collection provides in postman:

```
{
  "workflowFunctionID": 1,
  "workflowActionParameters": [
    {
      "name": "Description",
      "value": "Probando y wea2",
      "workflowFunctionParameterId": 2
    },
    {
        "name": "Price",
        "value": "25000",
        "workflowFunctionParameterId": 3
    }
  ]
}
```

As i mentioned it works perfectly. And this is the current code that am using Node.js:

```
main = async() => {
  try {
    const token = await acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(RESOURCE, CLIENT_APP_Id, CLIENT_SECRET, AUTHORITY);

    const request = {
      url: `${WORKBENCH_API_URL}/api/v1/contracts?workflowId=1&contractCodeId=1&connectionId=1`,
      method: "POST",
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization': `Bearer ${token.access_token}` },
      body: {
        workflowActionInput: {
          workflowFunctionID: 1,
          workflowActionParameters: [{
              "name": "description",
              "value": "cualkier wea"
            },
            {
              "name": "price",
              "value": "20000000"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }

    let res = await Swagger.http(request);

    console.log(res);
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
}

main();
```

How should i pass the body/form-data to the post request, or maybe using another package or code? Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

When you have api running in postman, just see this button named "code" i marked with black

- click on this button
- select language as node.js

It will show you code in node.js for that api, just copy that code and paste where required.
Here i am attaching picture kindly see this[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. I have one last question, it is necessary to add the Postman-Token field?

Comment: No, it's not necessary, you can remove postman-token & cache-control.

Comment: It worked, thank you!! Not even microsoft could have helped me!

Comment: Before you leave, is there a way to see the Node.js code but in a bearer token request from postman?

Comment: You can set the Authorization in the Authorization tab, then select **Preview Request** (important!). If you now click on the Code link, you'll see the headers including the Bearer token.

Comment: Maybe i didn't explain myself that well. I need to see the code that postman uses to request a token with OAuth 2.0.

Comment: It adds the bearer token in headers, See the headers part in the code you got from the postman.

Comment: Have a look at the "adal-node" package, that allows you to request a token: https://www.npmjs.com/package/adal-node

Comment: I had never seen this, I am sure you have saved me DAYS of work over the course of my career. Thank you!  Had such a hard time getting axios examples.  And thanks to the OP.