# How to create multipart/formdata request with attachment, using nodejs javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, google-cloud-functions

I need this same postman request to be converted to nodejs request. Didnt find any proper documentation or solution. It would be great if someone could help. Thanks !  https://ibb.co/vxpYBwX

This is what I have tried

```js
    var options = { method: 'POST',
              url: 'https://myapiurl',
              headers:
              {
                  "authorization" : "XXX",
                   "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"                 
              },
            form: {"name1":"abc","name2":"def"},
            attachments:????//not sure how to pass here
             
              };
            request(options,  (error, response, body)=> {
//response
 return;
      
              });
```

Comment: Is this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787030/convert-postman-api-call-to-node-js-call) useful? Please confirm so this post can be marked as duplicate.

Comment: Yes. it is not duplicate. i didnt find answer anywhere